# Diagnostic Logging - view current level?

Tags: 2013, logging

How do I view the current Diagnostic Logging settings for the SharePoint farm?

i.e. the settings for `Least critical event to report to the event log` and `Least critical event to report to the trace log`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `Get-SPLogLevel -Identity <value>`, e.g. `Get-SPLogLevel -Identity Database` to show the current level for the Database category. You can also exclude the Identity parameter to get all categories.

Answer (score 1):

Their are two ways to check this.

1. You can Use the powershell commands `[Get-SPLogLevel][1]`. This example displays throttle levels for all categories.
2. You can go to Central admin Site of farm. `Central Admin> Monitoring > Configure Diagnostic logging`. On this page you can expand all the categories and [check th level of Log.](http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/09/09/how-to-enable-verbose-log-mode-on-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot it was as easy as expanding out the various nodes. BTW, running `[Get-SPLogLevel][1]` doesn't work.